# Positioning ARKIT model

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am having a bit of trouble positioning a model on the screen. The model appears but it appears above me rather than in front of me. Ideally I want the model to appear where it is tapped. Please help!

This function here downloads the model successfully from AWS:

```
 private func dowloadModel(){
        let url = URL(string: "url_string")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let data = data{
                print(data)

                let documentDirectories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

                if let documentDirectory = documentDirectories.first{

                    let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Food.scn")
                    let dataNS : NSData? = data as NSData

                    try! dataNS?.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)

                    print("Saved!")
                }
            }

        }.resume()
    }
```

Here I render the model to the screen:

```
private func registerGestureRecogniser(){
        print("Tapped")
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
```

Here is the tapped function:

```
 @objc func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let documentDirectories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

        if let documentDirectory = documentDirectories.first{
            let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Food.scn")

            do{
                let scene = try SCNScene(url: fileURL, options: nil)
                let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Burger", recursively: true)!

                node.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);

                self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }

        }
    }
```

I also get the error:

```
Error: Failed to load <C3DImage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
node.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

you are positioning your model node at the rootNode of the scene, the position of which is determined by ARKit when the scene starts.

If you want the model to appear in front of the camera, then you need to grab the camera transform (`session.currentFrame?.camera.transform`), modify the `-z` component, and set that as the node's position. Or, if you want to place your model on a surface, do a raycast and use the `raycastResult` `simdWorldPosition` as your node's `simdWorldPosition`.

There are definitely examples of `raycast` around, but in brief, you first need to define a query:

```
let bounds = sceneView.bounds
let screenCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
let query = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: screenCenter, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
```

The above defines a raycast extending from the center of the screen and finding only horizontal surfaces. Please explore the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/3194595-raycastquery) for more information about `allowing` and `alignment` options.

You can then use the `session` to cast your ray:

```
session.raycast(query)
```

This will return an array of `ARRaycastResult`. You can examine them and choose if you wish, but I usually just take the `.first` one (note: it can be empty).

You would then want to take the translation component of your `raycastResult` transform and assign it as the `simdWorldPosition` of your node. Note that you can assign the entire transform to the nodes `simdWorldTransform` but this will also alter your node's orientation, which you may or may not want to do.

```
if let raycastResult = session.raycast(query).first {
    node.simdWorldPosition = raycastResult.worldTransform.translation
}
```

Oh, also, I find this little extension to be handy:

```
extension float4x4 {
    /**
     Treats matrix as a (right-hand column-major convention) transform matrix
     and factors out the translation component of the transform.
    */
    var translation: SIMD3<Float> {
        let translation = columns.3
        return SIMD3<Float>(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
    }
}
```

It's what allows you to do the `worldTransform.translation` in my code above.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I am brand new to this and I am unsure about how to implement this. If you could show me or link me to a tutorial it would be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do a `raycast` and place your model on a surface, or just put it in front of the camera?

Comment: I would like to do a raycast

Comment: Updated with some raycast explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this out tonight. Just at work atm!

Comment: Glad it helped!